# Display Alert when element passes a certain left position?

Tags: javascript

I have an element with a fixed position, it's animated with js and it's left position changes from 0 to 1000 randomly.

How can I display an alert each time the element crosses the 500px barrier?

I could only think of making an infinite loop that checks if leftpos < 500px and then using a variable to store whether he is right or left and display the alert when the variable changes but it seems over complicated though maybe it's the only solution.

Is there a better solution to doing this?

Comment: How is its position changed? Are you moving it with JS?

Comment: And you want to achieve this using php ????

Comment: I guess it's definitely JavaScript, not PHP...

Comment: how user "aus" edit this question . will the edit privilege there for 151?? \.-)

Comment: sorry, yes it's moved with javascript

Comment: I think aus just removed the PHP tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Javascript to move the element around you can add this check to the re-positioning code.

If it is somebody that drags and drops it, you could use the mouseup to to fire a javascript method to check location.

Comment: It actually moves using keydowns and a loop. I could save "left" or "right" to a variable depending on the element position and display the alert when the variable changes. Would this be a viable solution?

Comment: If I am not missing something, in the code block where you are actually moving it, you already know what the new left is going to be since you are moving it there. If it is above 500, alert. In that case you wouldn't need to save a global variable, you already have your new left to test from.

Comment: If they are moving it without Javascript, but using keydowns, you could bind a method to the keydown event with jQuery, like: `$('#element_name').keydown(function(){ if($(this).attr('left') > 500){ alert('Past half way to the right'); }});`

Comment: My problem is that doing it I get infinite alerts when passing the 500px mark. I don't know how to do just one alert each time he passes the limit.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha, yes, good point. As you said, you can create a global variable outside a function, this will make it visible to the whole document. Perhaps, in the code to move the element, if it is 500 or more and the notify variable is true, alert and set the variable to false, if it is false, do nothing, else if it is under 500, set the notify variable to true.: `if(position >= 500){ if(notify){ alert('Over half way to the right'); notify = false; }}else{ notify = true; }`

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side code. That mean the code is executed on the server and the output is sent to the client. Therefor, PHP can't do what you want. You need JavaScript. Check out something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and its position API and maybe a alert plugin if you want to get fancy:

- [Position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)
- [Alert](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/alert)

Alternatively, you could just use a standard JavaScript [alert](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp).

Comment: sorry, I tagged it as PHP by mistake. I know how to get the position and display the alert. What I was asking is how to listen to the change of position.